# Redirecting output of boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-timer

I'm widely using `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer` to measure the execution time of different functions and code blocks. I'm using a macro to simplify its use at the time I can easily disable it in production:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <string>

#ifdef LOG_MEASURE_TIME
#  define CPU_TIMER() boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t_##__LINE__(cpuTimerFormat(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__))
#endif
```

where

```
std::string cpuTimerFormat(const std::string &name, int line)
{
  const std::string time = " %ws wall, %us user + %ss system = %ts CPU (%p%)\n";

  return name + '@' + std::to_string(line) + time;
}
```

For tracing purposes, I'd like to redirect the output of `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer` from `std::cout` to `std::clog`, which is also linked to an optional log file.

```
// log_path is a std::filesystem::path from application options or command-line arguments
std::ofstream log_file;
if (!log_path.empty()) {
  log_file.open(log_path);
  if (log_file.is_open()) { std::clog.rdbuf(log_file.rdbuf()); }
}
```

I've being looking around and couldn't find a solution for it other than implementing my own `auto_cpu_timer` based on `boost::timer::cpu_timer`. Is it possible to do directly on `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm documenting it here because after googling and stackoverflowing for it I couldn't find the answer.*

I don't know why I didn't pay attention to it first, but there is a constructor for [`boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html#auto_cpu_timer-6) that receives a `std::ostream&`, so the solution is quite straight forward:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef LOG_MEASURE_TIME
#  define CPU_TIMER() boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t_##__LINE__(std::clog, cpuTimerFormat(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__))
#endif
```

For completeness, remember that [`std::clog`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog) is initially associated to `std::cerr`, which is usually also linked to the `stdout`. If the log file is optional, then `std::clog` may be streaming to the incorrect destination. If tracing should remain hidden except if the log file is specified, you can initially link `std::clog` to a null buffer:

```
std::clog.rdbuf(nullptr);
```